# npm install hangs on random package

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, package.json

When I run `npm i` in a project it hangs after some time on random picked package. The most common are with `-x` suffix like `infinity-x` or `to-string-x`. All other colleague macs are working without any problem.
What I have tried so far:

1. Removed package-lock and node_modules
2. Used yarn
3. reinstalled node
4. `npm cache clean --force`
5. Restarted mac
6. `ssh-add -A`
7. Tried other project to install - works
8. Checked out other branches

Everything above tried and did not succeed. Same hang every time.

**EDIT 1:**
I have left it in install, left for lunch. When I came back it continued installing after unlocking my mac and finished. I don't know why. I have tried to rerun after this again and the same hang occurs. Now it is `is-nil-x`.

**EDIT 2:**
Basically it took like 5-8 minutes to finish installing packages. Every time.

9. Switched to different corporate WiFi network
10. Switched to LAN
    Still same hangs occurs and it takes long time a lot longer to install than usually

Comment: What version of NPM do you use? Have you tried downgrading to some older versions?

Comment: did you try updating your npm or node? May be it is trying to build a package and failed to do so.

Comment: npm module build some module with python or any other interpreter . just use --verbose to check where it has been hang

Comment: @SebastianKaczmarek I have 6.4.1. I haven't tried to downgrade. All my colleagues are using the same npm version.

Comment: @Shaharyar I have uninstalled and reinstalled node completely

Comment: @MuhammadAli I have used `--verbose` as well during the process. Hangs on the same similar libs.

Comment: which similar library?

Comment: @MuhammadAli All the `-x` related ones mentioned in the question.